# Using getCalendarById() with Calendar IDs ending with "@import.calendar.google.com"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I want to create a script that lets me import a Google Calendar's events into a Google Sheet. I am using a standard script that successfully lets me import a Google Calendar with an ID ending in `@calendar.google.com`, however I am trying to import one with the ending `@import.calendar.google.com` and the same script doesn't work.

When I use a calendar with that ending as in the code below it gives me an error:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getEvents" of null.

in regards to variable `cal` in the code below.

Is there a way to make it work?

```
var mycal = "g12nnimsl582k0hmfl0baca64ffimels@import.calendar.google.com";
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date("January 1, 2019 00:00:00 CST"), new Date("December 31, 2019 23:59:59 CST"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the calendar which is failing directly shared with your user?

I had a similar issue a couple years ago and determined that calendars had to be explicitly shared with the user executing the script. Calendars which were publicly available or shared to a domain failed to be opened by CalendarApp.

Comment: Hello Cameron, I checked and the failing calendar was NOT directly shared. I've gone back and shared it with the user and it worked just fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Happy to help Ivan!  Please click the checkmark icon next to my answer to mark it as accepted/correct, this makes it easier for others with a similar issue to see you found a solution (and also awards me some reputation points :)